# How to develop against a web-based product with built-in server (not ASP.NET project)?

Tags: version-control, development-environment

We have an application at work which is web-based and comes with a bundled web server (Apache tomcat), and is for network monitoring/patch management. It allows for personalisation, all sorts of rules, custom UI design using proprietary components and definition language, and even custom code to fire on events (based on Java).

I am in a team of several developers, each of who will be customising this app to meet various requirements. As it's a server app, not a codebase, what's the best way to setup a dev environment for >1 user?

If there is one single shared VM with this app, I don't know how good source control like TFS would work with this sort of system? I think also, developers working on various parts of the project may even need the same file at the same time (though TFS does do multiple check-outs).

What is the best way to develop against this sort of product? Bare in mind, even with personal VMs and an instance of the app, changes have to be merged to one central instance. Something keeps making me think about how app-virtualisation could help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is just an instance of Tomcat (even though it was bundled) couldn't you put the whole Tomcat directory and all of its subdirectories under source control? You just need to check in the non-binary parts, so exclude all the .jar, .exe, .tar.gz and .dll files when you check in. That's what I would do, unless I misunderstood your question.

I'm not familiar with the source control software that you mentioned. I have been using SVN (which is free) and TortoiseSVN as a client (also free). Just an option if your software can't support what I've suggested.